# R ggplot: stat = "identity" is not working for some reason

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a datafile which looks something like this...

```
Rate <- runif(14, 0, 20)
Day <- c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
         "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
         "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
         "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
Grouper <- c(rep(1, 7), rep(2, 7))
df <- data.frame(Rate, Day, Grouper)
```

...and I want to make a bar chart with two bars for each day: one bar for `Grouper = 1` and one bar for `Grouper = 2`. The y-value is not a count, it's the `Rate` variable, so I need to use `stat = "identity"` to make it work...

```
# Set max chart height
maxlimit = max(df$Rate) * 1.1
# Actual plot code 
ggplot(df, aes(Day, Rate)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Grouper), position = "dodge") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, maxlimit)) + 
  theme_classic()
```

...but I am still getting the error `stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.` Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: You are calling the geom twice and don't change the default the second time.

Comment: Ah, understood. Thought I was following the style set up in the ggplot2 documentation, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was calling `geom_bar` twice. I thought I was supposed to do this, but I was wrong; the second call just re-sets the `geom_bar` settings, thus erasing the call to `stat=identity.` This code works:

```
ggplot(TSdata, aes(Day, Rate, group = Grouper, col = Grouper)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Grouper), position = "dodge") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, maxlimit)) + 
  theme_classic()
```